# DrawerToggle Hamburger icon not showing

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. currently, I am making an android app with a navigation drawer. I managed to add the drawer. and when slid it works properly. but my problem is I cannot manage to add a hamburger icon.

my minimum sdk version is 17

I tried every solution given in the previous problems but didn't work.

My main activity code

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        DrawerLayout drawer =(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        toggle.syncState();

    }
    // Menu icons are inflated just as they were with actionbar

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

my xml code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="left">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0E0E0"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@null"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: The simplest solution would be to add `myToolbar` as a third argument in the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor call. Otherwise, you'll have to do about three other things to get it working with the `ActionBar`.

Comment: @MikeM. Shouldn't it be a Drawer layout? I added that it gives me an error.

Comment: You're already passing the `DrawerLayout` as the second argument. The `Toolbar` would be the third: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout,%20androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar,%20int,%20int).

Comment: @MikeM. thanks. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following example:

> MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null) {

        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, myToolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(toggle != null) {
        toggle.syncState();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (toggle != null) {
        toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}

}
```

> activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0E0E0"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@null"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Text View"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:gravity="center">
</TextView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine, You just need to pass the toolbar object into the ActionBarDrawerToggle constructer as a third argument.

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, myToolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
```

here